# Input value to contract from web3

Tags: web3js, contract-debugging

I am pretty new to this so please bare with my ignorance!
I need to write some data to a contract on a private chain using a simple function that I defined. Here is the Solidity function:

```
 function createPatient(bytes32 firstName, bytes32 lastName, uint height, uint weight, bytes32 dob){
        PatientObjects newPatient = new PatientObjects(firstName, lastName, height, weight, dob);
        LogCreatedPatient(newPatient);
        patients.push(newPatient);
    }
```

It all works fine ifI use the Remix compiler online. I am now trying to access this function using web3. But I have no idea how I could do it. Here is what I have tried and the error message i got:

```
var createPatientForMedicalStaff = function(patient, MSaddress, provider, callback){
    console.log("in the eth api the value of patient is: " + JSON.stringify(patient));
    console.log("the address: " + MSaddress);
    var web3 = new Web3();
    web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider(provider));
    var getOrganisationDetailContract = web3.eth.contract(ethContracts.abiMedicalStaffObject).at(MSaddress);
    getOrganisationDetailContract.createPatient(patient, function(error, result){
        if (!error) {
            console.log("it worked!: " + result);
        } else {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
};
exports.createPatientForMedicalStaff = createPatientForMedicalStaff;
```

The object patient contains a json with all the inputs that the solidity function needs. and MSaddress is the address of the Solidity contract. I am sure that the address is correct since when i paste it in the remix compiler I can indeed access the said contract. However when I try to run this with web3 I get this error:

```
 Error: invalid address                                                     2017-03-16T19:59:13.347330+00:00 app[web.1]:     at inputAddressFormatter (/app/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/formatters.js:271:11)                                                                                                                2017-03-16T19:59:13.347331+00:00 app[web.1]:     at inputTransactionFormatter (/app/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/formatters.js:97:20)                                                                                                             2017-03-16T19:59:13.347332+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Array.map (native)                                                  2017-03-16T19:59:13.347332+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/method.js:89:28                     2017-03-16T19:59:13.347333+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Method.formatInput (/app/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/method.js:88:32)                                                                                                                        2017-03-16T19:59:13.347334+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Method.toPayload (/app/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/method.js:114:23) 2017-03-16T19:59:13.347334+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Eth.send [as sendTransaction] (/app/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/method.js:139:30)                                                                                                            2017-03-16T19:59:13.347336+00:00 app[web.1]:     at SolidityFunction.execute (/app/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/function.js:234:37)                                                                                                               2017-03-16T19:59:13.347335+00:00 app[web.1]:     at SolidityFunction.sendTransaction (/app/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/function.js:151:15)                                                                                                       2017-03-16T19:59:13.347336+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.createPatientForMedicalStaff (/app/ethAPI.js:117:35)         2017-03-16T19:59:13.347337+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/app.js:174:12                                                  2017-03-16T19:59:13.347339+00:00 app[web.1]:     at module.exports (/app/node_modules/express-stormpath/lib/middleware/authentication-required.js:25:12)                                                                                        2017-03-16T19:59:13.347337+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)                                                                                                       2017-03-16T19:59:13.347338+00:00 app[web.1]:     at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)         2017-03-16T19:59:13.347339+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/express-stormpath/lib/middleware/get-user.js:154:11                                                                                                                       2017-03-16T19:59:13.347340+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/express-stormpath/lib/helpers/expand-account.js:145:5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed two things:

I. You have to respect the function signature `function createPatient(bytes32 firstName, bytes32 lastName, uint height, uint weight, bytes32 dob)` which means you need to pass each attribute instead of the whole Javascript object :

```
var createPatientForMedicalStaff = function(patient, MSaddress, provider, callback){
    console.log("in the eth api the value of patient is: " + JSON.stringify(patient));
    console.log("the address: " + MSaddress);

    var web3 = new Web3();
    web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider(provider));
    var getOrganisationDetailContract = web3.eth.contract(ethContracts.abiMedicalStaffObject).at(MSaddress);

    getOrganisationDetailContract.createPatient(patient.firstName, patient.lastName, patient.height, patient.weight, patient.dob, function(error, result){
        if (!error) {
            console.log("it worked!: " + result);
        } else {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
};

exports.createPatientForMedicalStaff = createPatientForMedicalStaff;
```

II. Secondly Web3 send the transaction using the default account `web3.eth.defaultAccount` but it can happen this one isn't correctly set. To avoid that, refer to the list of available accounts controlled by your node

```
console.log(web3.eth.accounts);
```

And either assign an account as default account (first one for example)

```
web3.eth.defaultAccount=web3.eth.accounts[0]
```

Or configure the sender in the call using `from: 0x*******`

```
    getOrganisationDetailContract.createPatient(patient.firstName, patient.lastName, patient.height, patient.weight, patient.dob, {from: web3.eth.accounts[0]}, function(error, result){
    (...)
```